# Different authentication on entire site and specific location

Tags: nginx, authentication

I've got a question regarding a Nginx configuration.

I got this configuration below :

```
location / {
 auth_basic 'Restricted content';
 auth_basic_user_file /nginx/conf/authentication/.htpasswd;
}
location /admin {
 auth_basic 'Restricted content';
 auth_basic_user_file /nginx/conf/authentication/.admin-htpasswd;
}
```

The problem is that i got a prompt for password on the /admin page witch does not work either with the first password neither with the admin one.

How can i debug this ?

Comment: Check first that your second password file works correctly by using it for the first location.

Comment: Yes it is working

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this is to:

- enable error_log at the 'debug' level: add `error_log /var/log/log/nginx/error.log debug;` to the second stanza
- check ownership and permissions on `.admin-htpasswd`: are they the same as `.htpasswd`?
- change the auth_basic string of the second stanza to something different, i.e. `Admin restricted content`: does your browser show you the new text when accessing `/admin`?
- temporarily overwrite `.admin-htpasswd` with `.htpasswd`: can you authenticate using the first password now?